# Floer cohomology from mapping spaces of $\infty$ categories

Tags: homotopy-theory, sg.symplectic-geometry, big-picture, infinity-categories, floer-homology

There's a meta-observation (of Urs Schreiber, who attributes it to Ken Brown and Lurie) that 'cohomology theories come from mapping spaces of $(\infty,1)$ categories'. This is described in detail at the [nlab page on cohomology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cohomology#Idea)

I would like to understand if there's any non-contrived way that Floer-theoretic invariants fit into this picture.

I'm far from an expert. I'm aware of a number of works elucidating homotopy-theoretic aspects of Floer theory: for example 
the construction of Cohen-Jones-Segal, and the infinity category of Lagrangian cobordisms defined by Nadler-Tanaka. Do any of these constructions provide an answer to the question above?

Comment: I know nothing about Floer homology, but the observation of Urs Schreiber is just a complicated way of stating that we like when our cohomology theories are (co)representable (be it by spectra, motives or whatever object you find suitable).

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floer_homology#Floer_homotopy) mentions some recent work of Manolescu extending Cohen-Jones-Segal, seemingly in the direction of your question

Comment: You can also do worse than study the works of Thomas Kragh

Comment: Thanks! I was aware of the Manolescu and Abouzaid-Kragh lines of work, but didn't want to turn the question into a glossary of vaguely relates things none of which I understand very well :(

Comment: @Denis Nardin thanks for that enlightening comment, indeed the content of the question is whether Floer cohomology is representable in some category.

Comment: Cohomology \emph{theory} generally has a precise meaning i.e. there are certain axioms your cohomology groups satisfy(e.g. excision). Floer (co)homologies don't usually satisfy those literally. Though it is of course interesting to think about situations where Mayer-Vietoris, gluing formulas etc hold.

Comment: @algebrachallenged does it fail the conditions of Brown Representability theorem? Is there a place in literature where this is discussed?

Comment: You might be interested in checking out some of the abstracts from this summer school and conference from last year: https://sites.google.com/site/floerhomotopy2017/home

Comment: there was some work by Seidel's student Tim Large on the subject of Floer homotopy types (which may or may not be relevant)